# How to get all my database table values in a listbox with the for statement C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, for-loop, listbox

As a beginner in C# I am having some problems with getting all my values (and only the values - not the field names) out of my database table and list them in my listbox.

I did some research and found out that I could get all the field names of a specific table with the following code:

```
try
 {
   connection.Open();
   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
   string query = "select * from MyTable where Month='January'";

   command.CommandText = query;
   OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
   var columns = listBox5;

   for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
   {
      if (reader.GetName(i) != "Month" && reader.GetName(i) != "Id")
      {
                        columns.Items.Add(reader.GetName(i));
      }    
   }


   connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
}
```

This works perfectly for listing the field names (and not the field names Month and ID). Though now I also need to list all my values (that match with the corresponding field names). At first I thought to add them at the same time with the field names (above code) but this was to complicated for me. So then I try'd to list the values in another listbox with kinda the same code, but instead of using the GetName I used the GetValue. See code below:

```
try
{
   connection.Open();
   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
   command.Connection = connection;
   string query = "select * from MyTable";

   command.CommandText = query;
   OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

   var columns2 = listBox6;
   for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
   {    
      columns2.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());    
   }
   connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
}
```

This doesn't work though. I am getting the following error:

> ErrorSystem.InvalidOperationException: Data doesn't exist for the row/column at line ...

On this line:

```
columns2.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
```

Comment: My bad, I am getting the following error: ErrorSystem.InvalidOperationException: Data doesn't exist for the row/column at line (this line: columns2.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `Read()` on your reader before you can read records:

```
var columns2 = listBox6;

while (reader.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {    
        columns2.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());    
    }
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Advances the SqlDataReader to the next record. The default position of the SqlDataReader is before the first record. Therefore, you must call Read to begin accessing any data.